# Subtract rows and create a new row name

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, row, subtraction

I would like to subtract **Bay County** from **Florida** in this data frame and create a new row with the name **"Florida (-Bay County)"**.

Maybe group_modify and add_row (dplyr) would be a possibility?

```
year <- c(2005,2006,2007,2005,2006,2007,2005,2006,2007,2005,2006,2007)
county <- c("Alachua County","Alachua County","Alachua County","Baker County","Baker County","Baker County","Bay County","Bay County","Bay County","Florida","Florida","Florida")
pop <- c(3,6,8,9,8,4,5,8,10,17,22,22)
gdp <- c(3,6,8,9,8,4,5,8,10,17,22,22)
area <- c(3,6,8,9,8,4,5,8,10,17,22,22)
density<-c(3,6,8,9,8,4,5,8,10,17,22,22)
df <- data.frame(year, county,pop,gdp,area,density, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

| year | county | pop | gdp | area | density |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005 | Alachua County | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 2005 | Baker County | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 |
| 2005 | Bay County | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 2005 | Florida | 17 | 17 | 17 | 17 |
| **2005** | **Florida (-Bay County)** | **12** | **12** | **12** | **12** |
| 2006 | Alachua County | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 2006 | Baker County | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
| 2006 | Bay County | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
| 2006 | Florida | 22 | 22 | 22 | 22 |
| **2006** | **Florida (-Bay County)** | **14** | **14** | **14** | **14** |
| 2007 | Alachua County | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
| 2007 | Baker County | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 2007 | Bay County | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 2007 | Florida | 22 | 22 | 22 | 22 |
| **2007** | **Florida (-Bay County)** | **12** | **12** | **12** | **12** |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to try something with `group_modify` and `add_row`, you could consider something like this. Here, when using `add_row`, use `map` to `sum` up the data within the group, but not including "Florida" or "Bay County".

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  group_modify(
    ~ .x %>%
      add_row(
        county = "Florida (-Bay County)",
        !!! map(.x %>% 
                  filter(!county %in% c("Florida", "Bay County")) %>%
                  select(-county),
                sum)
        )
  )
```

**Output**

```
    year county                  pop   gdp  area density
   <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  2005 Alachua County            3     3     3       3
 2  2005 Baker County              9     9     9       9
 3  2005 Bay County                5     5     5       5
 4  2005 Florida                  17    17    17      17
 5  2005 Florida (-Bay County)    12    12    12      12
 6  2006 Alachua County            6     6     6       6
 7  2006 Baker County              8     8     8       8
 8  2006 Bay County                8     8     8       8
 9  2006 Florida                  22    22    22      22
10  2006 Florida (-Bay County)    14    14    14      14
11  2007 Alachua County            8     8     8       8
12  2007 Baker County              4     4     4       4
13  2007 Bay County               10    10    10      10
14  2007 Florida                  22    22    22      22
15  2007 Florida (-Bay County)    12    12    12      12
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(county != 'Florida' & county != 'Bay County') %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  bind_rows(summarise(., county = 'Florida (-Bay County)', 
                      across(where(is.numeric), sum))) %>%
  arrange(year)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 6
#> # Groups:   year [3]
#>    year county                  pop   gdp  area density
#>   <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1  2005 Alachua County            3     3     3       3
#> 2  2005 Baker County              9     9     9       9
#> 3  2005 Florida (-Bay County)    12    12    12      12
#> 4  2006 Alachua County            6     6     6       6
#> 5  2006 Baker County              8     8     8       8
#> 6  2006 Florida (-Bay County)    14    14    14      14
#> 7  2007 Alachua County            8     8     8       8
#> 8  2007 Baker County              4     4     4       4
#> 9  2007 Florida (-Bay County)    12    12    12      12
```